# Sleep Windows from Java

Tags: java, windows, sleep, standby

Is there command to use on windows from java to make the computer sleep?

Comment: Removed the hibernate tag as it refers to the ORM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it by executing a shell command, if you java app has enough rights to do so.  The command is...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep");
```

That and other commands are shown [here](http://unlockforus.blogspot.com/2008/03/shutdown-restart-lock-sleep-or.html).

Comment: even though the OP accepted this as the answer, future readers should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369122/sleep-windows-from-java/1369832#1369832 also.

Answer (score 8):

I currently solved this using https://github.com/twall/jna. Information about the call from http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/powrprof.SetSuspendState

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
public class WindowsSuspend {
  public static native boolean SetSuspendState(boolean hibernate, boolean forceCritical, boolean disableWakeEvent);

  static {
    if (Platform.isWindows())
      Native.register("powrprof");
  }
}
```

Call it than with `WindowsSuspend.SetSuspendState(false, false, false)`.

Answer (score 5):

Anyone suggesting rundll32 should be shot, very few functions are designed to be called by rundll32 and SetSuspendState is **not** one of them. You will get random behavior (Hibernate vs Standby and Forced vs not forced etc) See [this blog entry for more details](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx).

Comment: why the hate for this answer?  seems thoughtful and helpful.  At least comment when you -1.

Comment: OK.  So the RunDLL32 process ends up with a corrupted stack after calling the function.  Who cares? It can't 'infect' the parent process and by the time it occurs the function has already been called.

Comment: @Jherico: no, that's not the problem, the problem is, you will be calling SetSuspendState with UNKNOWN arguments, and since SetSuspendState will hibernate OR standby depending on the arguments, that's a bit of a problem

Comment: @Jherico: Also, if you look at the article you posted, you will notice that they tell you to disable/enable hibernation systemwide to "cure" the unknown/random arguments problem

Comment: Read blog entry. Don't get it. What is proper way?

Comment: @turbanoff Don't use rundll32 on functions not designed for rundll32 usage.

Comment: @Anders but it doesn't answer original question. All other answers suggest to use `rundll32`. So answer: `there is no proper way`. Right?

Comment: @turbanoff The proper way is to call `SetSuspendState` from a real programming language that follows the Windows ABI. For Java that means JNI if the function is not available in the language itself.

Answer (score 0):

No. You'd need to execute a separate binary via `Runtime.exec()`.

[This article](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/page-21882_35_0.html) suggests

```
rundll32 Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState
```

but I've not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the OnNow/ACPI Support [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995870.aspx).

There is also an old SO post that talks about it [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330560/adjust-volume-and-prevent-computer-from-standby-in-java-mac-and-windows-xp-v)
Probably the reverse of what you want. Might give you some clues though.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more complicated method but you could use `ProcessBuilder` to make a shell script (`.sh` or `.bat`) and execute that.