# How can I change the volume of an audio file in java

Tags: java, audio, volume

Here is my code:

```java
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file);
    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioIn);

    clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
```

What can I add to reduce the volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Java Sound API, you can set the volume with the MASTER_GAIN control.

Check this stackoverflow post: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953598/audio-volume-control-increase-or-decrease-in-java)

Comment: I cannot downvote yet but the question was asking changing volume of a FILE.